# Aforge get blobs from one image and extract same location from other

Tags: c#, image, aforge

I have an image that I do some processing to in order to separate the background from the foreground, creating a binary (black/white) image.

Using AForge, I am able to detect all blobs from the processed image, and return them.

So, I take my original image, copy it to "SourceImg", do some filtering to separate the background and make it a binary image, and then I can do the blob extraction properly.

```
    public static List<Bitmap> ApplyBlobExtractor(Bitmap SourceImg)
    {
        List<Bitmap> ImgLetters = new List<Bitmap>();
        AForge.Imaging.BlobCounter blobCounter = new AForge.Imaging.BlobCounter();

        // Sort order
        blobCounter.ObjectsOrder = AForge.Imaging.ObjectsOrder.XY;
        blobCounter.ProcessImage(SourceImg);
        AForge.Imaging.Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjects(SourceImg, false);

        // Adding images into the image list            
        AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage currentImg;
        foreach (AForge.Imaging.Blob blob in blobs)
        {
            currentImg = blob.Image;
            ImgLetters.Add(currentImg.ToManagedImage());
        }
        return ImgLetters;
    }
```

What I really want to do is use those blobs' information to extract the locations from the original, unprocessed image.

Ideally, I want to use the blob like a cookie cutter and grab extract them from my initial unprocessed image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AForge.Imaging.Filters.Intersect](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/7244211d-e882-09b1-965d-f820375af8be.htm) class using your blob's image and your source image.

Comment: damn... there was a filter that does that?  I just did it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming part of your image processing didn't resize the original image, why not just loop apply Crop transforms to the original image, setting the crop rectangle to the blob's Rectangle property?

Comment: the problem with this is I can grab the bounding box, but another blob may be within the bounding box.